# Update user in cognito nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I want to update username in cognito but at present aws provides only AdminUpdateUserAttributes feature but i don't want to update user attributes i want to update Username in cognito user pool is it possible please tell me

Comment: Hi Aditya, Hope you are doing good. Have you found any solution?